# Spring Boot running data.sql before creating entities in presence of schema.sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**Note : I have opened an issue on the Spring boot repository. Here's is the link**

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9048

I'm trying to insert some rows in my entities for testing on developer machine using H2 Database. I'm using `data.sql` for this.

It works fine, entities are created and then `data.sql` is run to insert data in the tables produced by the entities.

However I need to create some other tables for which there are no entity classes, so I'm using `schema.sql` for those. Here's the issue, as soon as I add `schema.sql` to the project, Spring Boot runs `data.sql` before creating entities, which ends in `Table not found` exception.

> How can I get `data.sql` working with the `schema.sql` and entity
>   classes at the same time ?

Here's sample code for the project.

Git link for functional maven project to reproduce the issue.

https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/SpringBootSchemaSqlIssue.git

```java
package com.test;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestDataSqlApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestDataSqlApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="USER_DETAILS")
class UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**schema.sql**

```sql
create table test(id int(10), name varchar(10));
```

**data.sql**

```sql
insert into USER_DETAILS VALUES(1, 'user1');
insert into USER_DETAILS VALUES(2, 'user2');
insert into USER_DETAILS VALUES(3, 'user3');
```

**Edit** *

As suggested by `@abaghel` renaming `data.sql` to `import.sql` works, however `import.sql` runs unconditionally. That's not what I need.

For the testing, I have a maven profile which activates a specific `spring.datasource.platform = h2`, which in turn forces spring to load `schema-h2.sql` and `data-h2.sql`. Unfortunately platform has no effect on the `import.sql` so renaming it to `import-h2.sql` stops Spring from loading it.

Here's the branch with the platform changes to reproduce this issue.

https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/SpringBootSchemaSqlIssue/tree/platform-h2

Comment: `import.sql` isn't run by spring it is detected by hibernate and loaded as such. So it doesn't adhere to the rules that Spring Boot has for the `data.sql` and `schema.sql`. Also combining different ways of managing your database is probably not a good thing (imho) and can be confusing. I would suggest disabling hibernate from creating the schema and you put all the schema creation logic in the `schema.sql`.]

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for information, are you saying it can't be done ? I can't figure out what could be the reasoning behind invoking `data.sql` before entities are created only in presence of `schema.sql` when all it does is cause issues. Project requires content from some existing tables, which I'm creating in the `schema-h2.sql` only for testing. New tables are to be generated by entities, so I can't get away with using just the one.

Comment: Why not, you can put the whole schema in `schema.sql` imho you shouldn't rely on hibernate creating the schema (at least not in your production environment you want more control over that). Combining the `schema.sql`, `data.sql` together with hibernate is tricky.

Comment: I believe this to be an issue with Spring Boot, have created bug on the github and added link to it in the post above. Thanks for your response. I'm going to try to do it with Java code instead of `data.sql`.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question but I was facing the same issue in 2022.
It seems that the `data.sql` file by default is executed before the schema creation by Hibernate. To avoid this, you need to set the property:
`spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`

More information here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database#2-hibernate-and-datasql

Comment: Thanks, I haven't tried it, I will update the Git repository in question if this works.

Answer (score 2):

Rename your `data.sql` to `import.sql` and your application will start without any error. Please see related document at [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, it does work with the `import.sql`, however I have to make it work with the an active `spring.datasource.platform` value. I have edited the question with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I have the `data.sql` and `schema.sql` files in my project. My solution was to add in the `schema.sql` file **the table creation DDL** used by the commands in the `data.sql` file.